# How to install PostGIS extension for Postgres in an instance of EC2 in AWS running Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgis

I'm trying to install PostGIS extension in Postgres 15 in a EC2 instance of  AWS running Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023). But, the method that I have used previously with Amazon Linux 2 doesn't work with the new version. Basically, AL2023 doesn't include extras, so the command `amazon-linux-extras` used previously to install the extension is not available now. I check in AWS FAQ and this package is no part now of Amazon Linux 2023 [(AL2023 FAQ)](https://aws.amazon.com/es/linux/amazon-linux-2023/faqs).

I know that RDS in AWS includes PostGIS, but my current need doesn't require an extra server, different from a single EC2 instance for app and DB. On the other hand, maybe some repositories for Redhat/Centos family allow the installation but I have not found information about that that will be safe.

As a reference output for command looking at available packages gives me

```bash
$ yum search post*
Last metadata expiration check: 2:05:28 ago on Fri Jun  9 20:36:37 2023.
=========================================== Name & Summary Matched: post* ============================================
postfix.x86_64 : Postfix Mail Transport Agent
postfix-cdb.x86_64 : Postfix CDB map support
postfix-ldap.x86_64 : Postfix LDAP map support
postfix-lmdb.x86_64 : Postfix LDMB map support
postfix-mysql.x86_64 : Postfix MySQL map support
postfix-pcre.x86_64 : Postfix PCRE map support
postfix-perl-scripts.x86_64 : Postfix utilities written in perl
postfix-pgsql.x86_64 : Postfix PostgreSQL map support
postfix-sqlite.x86_64 : Postfix SQLite map support
postgresql15.x86_64 : PostgreSQL client programs
postgresql15-private-devel.x86_64 : PostgreSQL development header files for this build of PostgreSQL server
postgresql15-server-devel.x86_64 : PostgreSQL development header files and libraries
================================================ Name Matched: post* =================================================
postgresql15-contrib.x86_64 : Extension modules distributed with PostgreSQL
postgresql15-docs.x86_64 : Extra documentation for PostgreSQL
postgresql15-llvmjit.x86_64 : Just-in-time compilation support for PostgreSQL
postgresql15-plperl.x86_64 : The Perl procedural language for PostgreSQL
postgresql15-plpython3.x86_64 : The Python3 procedural language for PostgreSQL
postgresql15-pltcl.x86_64 : The Tcl procedural language for PostgreSQL
postgresql15-private-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required only for this build of PostgreSQL server
postgresql15-server.x86_64 : The programs needed to create and run a PostgreSQL server
postgresql15-static.x86_64 : Statically linked PostgreSQL libraries
postgresql15-test.x86_64 : The test suite distributed with PostgreSQL
postgresql15-test-rpm-macros.noarch : Convenience RPM macros for build-time testing against PostgreSQL server
postgresql15-upgrade.x86_64 : Support for upgrading from the previous major release of PostgreSQL
postgresql15-upgrade-devel.x86_64 : Support for build of extensions required for upgrade process
=============================================== Summary Matched: post* ===============================================
collectd-postgresql.x86_64 : PostgreSQL plugin for collectd
dovecot-pgsql.x86_64 : Postgres SQL back end for dovecot
libpq.x86_64 : PostgreSQL client library
perl-Module-Package.noarch : Postmodern Perl Module Packaging
perl-autouse.noarch : Postpone load of modules until a function is used
psutils.noarch : PostScript utilities
python3-dnf-plugin-post-transaction-actions.noarch : Post transaction actions Plugin for DNF
t1lib.x86_64 : PostScript Type 1 font rasterizer
texlive-esstix.noarch : PostScript versions of the ESSTIX, with macro support
texlive-pspicture.noarch : PostScript picture support
texlive-pstricks.noarch : PostScript macros for TeX
```

Comment: You have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Another change in AL2023. Now the default package manager is DNF instead of YUM.

Answer (score 0):

There are already Postgres packages for AL2023. However, there is no package for Postgres 16, and you may need or want to compile it yourself for other reasons, such as extensions, or to have a command line client that can connect to an RDS instance.

AL2023 is quite different from AL2. Yum is gone, replaced with DNF.

Here is how I got Postgres to build easily from source on AL2023. First, as root, install some requirements:

```
dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools'
dnf install readline readline-devel
dnf install openssl-devel libicu-devel
```

Then as non-root download, configure and compile:

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v16.1/postgresql-16.1.tar.gz
tar xfz postgresql-16.1.tar.gz
cd postgresql-16.1
./configure  --with-ssl=openssl
make
```

Then as root, install:

```
make install
```

You will now have postgres installed in `/usr/local/pgsql`. It will not be in the startup scripts; you'll need to do that yourself.

The `--with-ssl=openssl` is critical if you are going to use the psql command line client to connect to RDS instances. Without that it will not be able to connect and will give an error about the hba file, which isn't the problem.

I needed a Postgres 16 client so I could connect to a Postgres 16 RDS instance without errors, for management and also so I could install the extension to dump the database to an s3 instance. The good news is, with the commands above, building and installing Postgres is quick and easy.